# Mechanism to read flags from command line arguments in Tcl

Tags: command-line, tcl, command-line-arguments

Is there a built in way in Tcl to read flags from the command line arguments, similar to `GetOptions` in Perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [cmdline](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/cmdline.html) package from [tcllib](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/) is probably a good fit.  Also there are lots of other custom code to do this sort of things--for instance, see [this](http://wiki.tcl.tk/14717) and [this](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1623) pages on the wiki and the pages they link to.